# Insert Values into Table Using Parameter

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, temp-tables

I am creating a temp table that has one column and I am trying to add multiple rows of data into that column. Is it possible to put these string/varchar values into a parameter/variable to be inserted into the table? Instead of listing them out ('x'),('y'),('z') for example. Thanks

Comment: which RDBMS are you using? in SQL Server, you can define user-defined table data type to achieve this.

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server. How would I go about defining this data type?

Comment: See also [Use Table-Valued Parameters (Database Engine)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/use-table-valued-parameters-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) and [Table-Valued Parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have user defined Table-Type as shown below:

User-Defined Table Type can be created via script below or via SSMS as shown in image:

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[my_array] AS TABLE(
    [string_value] [varchar](500) NOT NULL -- Define your string column
)
GO
```

[image]

and use it as below:

```
declare @myList as [my_array];
insert into @myList values('x'),('y'),('z'); -- You can insert from existing table
```

Retrieve the values as below:

```
select * from @myList
```

Fiddler is [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=8dfe2d4a0b668b30f7dcf652d1e18d57).